# javascript inside laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Hi friend's need help pls

This is my java script code .

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="button" style="float: right;" value="{!! trans("main.remove") !!}" class="remove-box btn btn-danger">'); 

 $("#contactcount").val(counter);   
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    counter++;
     });
```

I have try this method . but i got error so please tell me how to solve:

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
newTextBoxDiv.after().html({!! @if(@$usertypes['0']['type'] == 'Admin') !!}+'<input type="button" style="float: right;" value="{!! trans("main.remove") !!}" class="remove-box btn btn-danger">
+{!! @endif !!}'); 
$("#contactcount").val(counter);   
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

counter++;
});
```

Comment: java script inside laravel  applying

Comment: My eyes.... O.O

It would help if you post the error when you ask someone to solve your error

Answer (score 0):

Creating JavaScript on the fly with PHP is a terrible practice, never do that.

Some of the reasons:

- you're generating JS for each and every request
- browser redownloads JS files again with every loaded page, so website becomes really slow
- you can't minify these JS files

This is terrible:

```
value="{!! trans("main.remove") !!}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it all wrong. The syntax in these two cases:

```
 value="{!! trans("main.remove") !!}"
```

and

```
{!! @endif !!}
```

is Blade, it's not HTML. That code needs to be processed by Laravel in order to produce the results you expect. That means the code needs to run on the server. JavaScript runs on the browser. Adding Blade code on the fly with JS will do nothing

Comment: Hi dimlucas,  it is working good, now i am asking  .html () inside how to use laravel  code  for if condition